# How to remove . (dot) from email before @ using regex?

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to remove any dots before @ in an email address using regex. For eg:

```
Input- abc.xyz@gmail.com
Output- abcxyz@gmail.com

-- Tried the below expression but it didn't work.

"^[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+@([A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$"
```

Comment: Which Programming language you are using ?

Comment: I'm not using any programming language. It's a inhouse product.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Where are you trying to remove it ? Are you using any text editor ?

Answer (score 1):

You could match a dot and assert optional non whitespace chars excluding an @ to the right if a lookahead is supported.

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
\.(?=[^\s@]*@)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iOkj54/1)

You could make the pattern in the lookahead also more specific instead of only asserting an @ char:

```
\.(?=[^\s@]*@[^\s@.]+\.[^\s@.])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pupg0R/1)

Comment: This works in the regex demo but not in the product I'm using. thanks!

Comment: Do you know if this would be the supported in Perl?

Comment: @Bishu Yes this pattern will also work in perl.